# How to select a person from recyclerview and send it to the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, dialog, click

I am working on a app that controls tasks. I have to choose a person from a list to be the handler of the task. I have made a TextView that when clicked opens a DialogFragment that contains a recyclerview. How do I select a person from the recyclerView and send it back to the activity. I have tried working with interfaces but that hasn't worked yet.

Below are DialogFragment and the MainActivity:

*AlertDialogFragment*

```
RecyclerView recyclerViewPersons;
List<PERSON> personList = new ArrayList<>();
PersonsAdapter personsAdapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_persons_list, container);


    recyclerViewPersons = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPersons);


    recyclerViewPersons.setLayoutManager(new  LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
    personsAdapter = new PersonsAdapter(getActivity());
    personsAdapter.setData(personList);
    recyclerViewPersons.setAdapter(personsAdapter);

    return v;
}


public void setAdapterData(List<PERSON> personList) {
    this.personList = personList;
}
```

}

*MainActivity*

```
PersonsAdapter personsAdapter;
final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
final AlertDialogFragment alertDialogFragment = new AlertDialogFragment();

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

txtPersons.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        alertDialogFragment.setAdapterData(personList);
        alertDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "dialog recycler");


    });
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define an interface(which sends Person data) in Fragment & let it be implemented in the Activity.

Then, define one more interface in Recycler Adapter & let it be implemented in the Fragment. This interface will get the information after clicking on Recycler item. Invoke this interface in  Adapter's layout on click.

Then finally whatever data you get in fragment, pass it back to activity via first interface.
Hope this helps?

Comment: I managed to send the data from Adapter to DialogFragment but can't really send it to the Activity. Is there a trick to sending data from DialogFragment to Activity?

Answer (score 1):

You said that you managed to send the data from Adapter to DialogFragment. Now you can send this data from DialogFragment to Activity.

For this you can create another interface inside or outside the DialogFragment. Then you can implements this fragment with the activity and override this interface with its body.

Now, inside the DialogFragment override the onAttach method and instantiate this inferface instance.

**Interface**

```
public interface OnMyInterface {
    public void onMyData(your data);
}
```

**DialogFragment**

```
private OnMyInterface onMyInterface;

public ForgotAndResetPasswordFragment() {}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_your_layout, container, false);
}

@Override
public View onViewCreated(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //send the data to activity using on onMyInterface
    onMyInterface.onMyData(your data);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
   super.onAttach(context);

   try {
      onMyInterface = (OnMyInterface) context;

   } catch (ClassCastException e) {
      throw new ClassCastException(context.toString());
   }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MyActivity implements OnMyInterface {
    @Override
    public void onMyData(your data) {
        //get this data
    }
}
```

Or you can try this approach also:
https://camposha.info/source/android-data-passing-fragment-activity-via-intent